# HP Proliant DL180 G6 HHD failure and replacement

Tags: hard-drive, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, drive-failure

One of the HP HDD in our HP Proliant DL180 G6 had failed, I've replaced the failed HDD with a standard 1 TB Seagate HDD, the Array controller won't start rebuilding on a Seagate, I had the new Seagate HDD in for about a week and the controller status reads interim rebuild.

I've checked the health of the failed HP HHD and it reads as OK, I've put it back into HP Proliant and array controller status reads as rebuilding, I left it overnight and its status still reads 0%.

Should the Controller be taking this long to rebuild the HHD?

If the drive doesn't rebuild do I need HP HHD or can use anyone that I pick up at my lock Computer supply store?

Answer (score 0):

SmartArray controllers require hot-swap for rebuild start. You can see 'interim rebuild' status if you have changed the drive offline.
Non-HP drives are working well usually.

SmartArray controllers rarely mark healthy drive as bad. 0% rebuild usually mark drive problems.
How did you checked old drive health? Good idea is to look at SMART values and perform MHDD/victoria test if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The server uses a SAS controller, not a SATA controller. I'm a little embarrassed that such a simple mistake cause such a big problem. Hopefully, this will help out a user in the future.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFfIY.jpg)

Comment: I'm using plain SATA HDD on HP SmartArray controllers without any problems.

Comment: SmartArray controllers fully support both SAS and SATA devices.  This should not have been your problem.  You can't mix SAS and SATA inside the same logical volume, but you can connect them to the same controller.